# Fatal error: Index Out of range? BUT IS IT?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a very weird array and I am not sure what I am missing, something very simple I am sure. Here is my code, This code loops a struct with arrays of objects and variables and attempts to find the objects which category = 1, when this is true, it sends the array of objects into another array. Everything works fine, until I try to copy the array into the sorted array, more comments in code. I am trying to sort a tableView when the user clicks a certain category, the 4 possible categories are 1,30,31,32 (don't ask why)

```
var courses = [Course]()
var sortedCourses = [Course]()
@objc func catOthersButtonObj(_ sender: UIButton){ //<- needs `@objc`
    var count = 0
    let courseCount = courses.count
    let otherCat = 1

    // set count to loop the number of detected arrays
    // this category looks for the number 1

    print("courseCount = " + String(courseCount)) // to debug if courseCount is accurate, it is
    //let noOfCat = courses.categories.count

    while (count < courseCount)
    {

        print("count = " + String(count)) // to debug if count is increasing every loop, it is
        let totalNoCat = (courses[count].categories?.count)!
        var catCount = 0

        // while entering a loop of arrays of objects, it searches for the array "categories" and sets totalNoCat = number of categories, this is neccesary because one object can have many categories
        // catCount is used to loop through the number of detect categories

        if (totalNoCat == 0)
        {
            break
        }

        // If no categories is detected, next array

        while (catCount < totalNoCat)
        {
            print("totalNoCat = " + String(totalNoCat))
            print("catCount = " + String(catCount))

            // debug, check if totalNoCat is detected
            // debug, catCount if number of categories is detected and added
            if (courses[count].categories?[catCount] == otherCat)
            {
                print("category Detected = " + String((courses[count].categories?[catCount])!))
                // see if category is 1, when it is 1, this is triggered, so its working fine
                let currentNoSortedCourses = sortedCourses.count
                print("currentNoSortedCourses = " + String(currentNoSortedCourses))
                // check the number of sorted array, this is to add array into the next array
                // if there is 0 number of sorted arrays, then sorted[0] should be course[detectarray category = 0 array]
                //print(courses[count]) checks if courses[count] has data, it does
                sortedCourses[currentNoSortedCourses] = courses[count] //where the error is
                //here it is sortedCourses[0] = courses[7] ( 7 is which the array detected the correct category
                break
            }
            catCount = catCount + 1
            print("Category Detected = " + String((courses[count].categories?[catCount - 1])!))

            //debug, if category not 1, show what it is

        }
        count = count + 1
    }

}
```

---

```
Print results

courseCount = 50
count = 0
totalNoCat = 2
catCount = 0
Category Detected = 31
totalNoCat = 2
catCount = 1
Category Detected = 30
count = 1
totalNoCat = 2
catCount = 0
Category Detected = 31
totalNoCat = 2
catCount = 1
Category Detected = 30
count = 2
totalNoCat = 1
catCount = 0
Category Detected = 30
count = 3
totalNoCat = 2
catCount = 0
Category Detected = 32
totalNoCat = 2
catCount = 1
Category Detected = 30
count = 4
totalNoCat = 2
catCount = 0
Category Detected = 32
totalNoCat = 2
catCount = 1
Category Detected = 30
count = 5
totalNoCat = 1
catCount = 0
Category Detected = 32
count = 6
totalNoCat = 2
catCount = 0
Category Detected = 32
totalNoCat = 2
catCount = 1
Category Detected = 30
count = 7
totalNoCat = 1
catCount = 0
category Detected = 1
currentNoSortedCourses = 0
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: What is the question? Yes, if you get out of bounds, it is out of bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without going much into the structure of the code and how it can be written in a more "Swifty" way, I can see the problem is that this is not a good way to append to an array in Swift.

```
            let currentNoSortedCourses = sortedCourses.count
            sortedCourses[currentNoSortedCourses] = courses[count]
```

This is accessing an index that is out of bounds and causes a crash. To append to an array in Swift use `append` method.

```
        sortedCourses.append(courses[count])
```

Whilst I'm here I might as well tell you that a better way (one liner) to solve your problem probably be something like this

```
    sortedCourses = courses.filter { $0.categories.contains(1) }
```

Comment: your one liner works like magic, Thanks SOOO MUCH, you make my codes look ancient!

Comment: Oh man, only if i knew i didn't need to go through that logic to code all that ahead of time